# jQuery star rating system with a value for every star

Tags: jquery, forms

I am having a problem with my jQuery code, I would like every star to have a Value.
So star one is 1/5, star two is 2/5 and so on.
(Value="1/5")
I use PHP to send the results of but it uses Values.
The plan is to use this star rating system in forms.

I have put the code in to jsFiddle. Link: http://jsfiddle.net/trickedgaming/2Q5cw/

```
<div id="stars"></div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example-1').ratings(10).bind('ratingchanged', function (event, data) {
        $('#example-rating-1').text(data.rating);
    });

    $('#stars').ratings(5).bind('ratingchanged', function (event, data) {
        $('#example-rating-2').text(data.rating);
    });
});
```

The rest of the code is in on the jsFiddle page.

Comment: Hi, I use Ajax tolkit and never had problems: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Rating/Rating.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `#example-rating-...` elements that you're attempting to access.

Add:

```
<input type="text" name="rating" value="" id="example-rating-2" />
```

And change `text()` to `val()`:

```
$('#example-rating-2').val(data.rating);
```

You should see the value change when the stars are clicked. Make the input type `hidden` when you're done testing...

Comment: Yes that seems to work, but it wont send it to the email
PHP:

    $stars = $_POST['stars'];

    $formcontent=" 
    Stars: $stars";

Comment: It's in `$_POST['rating']`. Change the input name to `stars` if you want it in `$_POST['stars']`